# How to handle thread returns Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a ruby script in which I'm parsing a large csv file.  Ihave everything handled and working fairly well, except for how to deal with the thread's return values.  I have:

```
length = (ses.size/4).ceil
ses.each_slice(length) do |x|
    threads << Thread.new { a,b = splat x }
end

threads.each { |thr|
    thr.join
}
```

'splat' returns to temp files that need to appended to the output files out1 and out2.  I'm stumbling on where exactly to do that/how to get that information.  If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, first, when you pass the 'x' into the thread, it's safer to make it thread-local by changing this:

```
threads << Thread.new { a,b = splat x }
```

Into this:

```
threads << Thread.new(x) { |x| a,b = splat x }
```

Next, to get the return value out, you join using [:value](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-value).

So here's a quick demo I whipped up:

```
dummy = [
  ['a.txt', 'b.txt'],
  ['c.txt', 'd.txt'],
  ['e.txt', 'f.txt'],
  ['g.txt', 'h.txt'],
  ['i.txt', 'j.txt'],
  ['k.txt', 'l.txt']
]

threads = dummy.map do |pair|
  Thread.new(pair) { |val| val }
end

vals = threads.map(&:value) # equiv. to 'threads.map { |t| t.value }'
puts vals.inspect
```

Crib off that and it should get you where you want to go.